# Compute the derivative of $ y^{2}+2 x y-2 x^{2} y+x^{2}=6 $ using implicit differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So far my working out is as goes:

\begin{equation}
y^{2}+2 x y-2 x^{2} y+x^{2}=6
\end{equation}

Finding the differential we therefore get

\begin{equation}
2 y \frac{d y}{d x}+2 \frac{d y}{d x}-2 x \frac{d y}{d x}+2 x=6
\end{equation}

To make the function=0 we do

\begin{equation}
2 y \frac{d y}{d x}+2 \frac{d y}{d x}-2 x \frac{d y}{d x}-6=0
\end{equation}

From here how do you get the differential with respect to x on its own?

Comment: When you differentiate the very first equation, the differentiation of $6$ is zero, since it is a constant

Answer (score 2):

Let $$y^2+2xy-2x^2y+x^2=6$$

Taking the derivative on $x$ we get (remember $y=y(x)$, so we have a product rule to work with)

$$2y\frac{dy}{dx}+2y+2x\frac{dy}{dx}-4xy-2x^2\frac{dy}{dx}+2x=0$$

This equality is equivalent to

$$\frac{dy}{dx}(2y+2x-2x^2)=-2y+4xy-2x$$

Then,

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-2y+4xy-2x}{2y+2x-2x^2}$$

From here you can rewrite as you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

You can just solve for $dy/dx$ no? Like factorise and bring everything that is not $dy/dx$ to the RHS. You also made a mistake differentiating $2xy$

Comment: I thought for the differential of 2xy it would be 2dy/dx how come it isn't?

Comment: youre differentiatinf a product of functions, namely $2x$ and $y$. You cant ignore $y$ and treat it like a constant to to obtain $2x$ after differentiating.